# Looking for a remote switch triggered by brief power off then on

Tags: remote-control, remote

I'm looking for a "remote switch" that can be turned on by a brief interruption to the power supply.

Scenario: I have 2 lights on 1 circuit.  I cannot run wires back to the main switch but I can access the wires where they split to the 2 individual lights.  What I'd like is :  After turning the light switch on the second light is normally off.  I'd like to turn the second light on by briefly turning the light switch off then on again.  Obviously when I turn the light switch off both lights go out.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Either a circuit diagram so i can build the "remote" switch or premade solution would be ok.  This "remote switch" would go where the wiring splits to the two individual lights.

I have an outdoor sensor light that does a similar thing.  Turn it on and it is in sensor mode.  Turn it quickly off then on again and the light is on until I turn it off.

I'm trying to avoid wireless as I'm concerned the remote switch will lose its connection setting when it doesn't have power for long time.

240v light circuit

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a recommendation for a particular switch? It sounds like it and, if so, then this is off-topic.

Comment: Your scenario is unclear. Please read through your text and assume you have NO idea of what is wanted and ensure that your text tells us. At present it doesn't. || IMPORTANT: Would a circuit that does the job be suited or do you only want a premade solution.

Comment: You need to store a state and have that state determine whether second set of lights turns on at power on.  Capacitor can store DC voltage as a state while inductor does same for current.